# How to prevent navigating to the type declaration of a symbol for some types of files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webstorm

For example I have some AngularJs code in file `a.js`:

```
$scope.configuration.functionThatDefinedSomeWhere()
```

Using this [feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigating-to-declaration-or-type-declaration-of-a-symbol.html) for WebStorm I can navigate to the place where function `functionThatDefinedSomeWhere` defined, let's name this place `b.js` Now everything ok.

But, if I had mock for this function in test, navigation linked to the test file `a.test.js`, not to the `b.js`.

So, I didn't find any way to change linking, perhaps somebody know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please follow [WEB-18988](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18988) for updates;
the only way to change linking is excluding your `a.test.js` from indexing (by marking it as plain text, for example). But you will lose syntax highlighting in spec files then, so it doesn't look like a valid solution

Comment: thanks for confirmation that we don't have another way.